# Objective-C++ pre-compiled headers

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos, objective-c++

I'm using a C++ library (it happens to be in an iPad application, but I'm not sure that should make any difference) and would really like to have the headers pre-compiled to speed up the builds, but xCode seems to run the pre-compiled header file through the C compiler rather than the C++ one.

Is there a way to get it to use the right compiler? I've already changed all of my source files from .m to .mm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Xcode docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeBuildSystem/800-Reducing_Build_Times/bs_speed_up_build.html), a compiled header is generated for each language variant.  So if you bracket your #include with guard macros, it should work i.e.

```
#if defined __cplusplus
#include "mycplusplusheader.h"
#endif
```

Comment: In the same way, you can use `#if defined __OBJC__` to include Objective-C only code.